# ModuleNotFoundError :No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-poetry, modulenotfounderror

I have still run into this issue after installing pandas in my local/virtual environment.

My project is trying to scrape some data from a website. Its current structure is

```
project/
  website/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py: The CLI for running the merger directly.
    helperfunc.py: The file where all the global functions are.
    merger.py: The file containing the class declaration and definition for merger.
    dataframe.py
```

I encounter the error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
File "/Users/Project-main/project/website/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dataframe import *
  File "/Users/Project-main/Project/website/dataframe.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I am 100% certain I have installed pandas so I would like for any advice on this error. At the same time, I have also use click and office365 module which I have also installed in poetry. However it still shows a `Import "module" could not be resolvedPylance` error as well. I don't if it is related to my error mentioned above.

My suspicion is that since this project will scrape data to onedrive which the credentials is currently outdated which may lead to the fail execution of the script?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? Have you enabled the virtual environment where pandas is installed?

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py` This is the path of the system python - it definitely looks like your virtual environment is not active.

Comment: The code I am using is created by others. So I have downloaded the code and edit in my vscodestudio. When this project is created it is created poetry. So I thought it is in a virtual environment already. Is there anyway I can activate the virtual environment? I have try poetry shell but it seems like it will open a new shell.

Comment: I have activate my virtual environment but still the same error pops up ? Do you have any idea on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Check pandas is installed in your virtual-env or not - try
`pip freeze`

Comment: Pandas is installed in both my local/virtual machine